# Divs not auto resizing height inside another div

Tags: html, css, resize, clearfix

### The solution has been found. The code is below. Thank you to everyone who helped.

The Solution was to clear the float, the code below fixed it for me.

```
.div#content:after {
content:"";
display:table;
clear:both;
}
```

Thanks Again.

---

### Original Question

I have 2 Divs, one being "Content" where all the content of my site is in. And another div named "updates". I want the div "content" to resize its height so that all the divs inside of it and fit. 
Here's an image explaining my problem easier [Imgur Link, Not high enough rep to post image directly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb4Vd.jpg)

Here's my full source code (html) (along with the css of content div and updates div.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>MCSocial</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.tinycircleslider.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="left">MCFish</li>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="http://social.minecraft.uk.to/news/">News</a></li>               
                     <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <a href="#"><div id="block">
                <img src="img/mojang.jpg" height="200px" width="850px">
            </div></a>

            <a href="#"><div id="block">
                <img src="img/minecraft.jpg" height="200px" width="850px">
            </div></a>

            <div id="updates">
                <img src="img/update.png" height="48px" width="140px">
                <!--post updates here-->
                <h3 class="sub-title">Update 1.5</h3>
                <p class="list">Added a new homepage! More simple to navigate! Enjoy!<br>Please send me some feedback <a href="#" class="sub-link">here!</a></p>

                <h3 class="sub-title">Update 1.4</h3>
                <p class="list">Cleaned up code!</a></p>

                <h3 class="sub-title">Update 1.3</h3>
                <p class="list">Added new themes! Check them out!</a></p>

                <h3 class="sub-title">Update 1.2</h3>
                <p class="list">Renamed Site: from MinecraftFishing to MCFish!</a></p>

                <h3 class="sub-title">Update 1.0</h3>
                <p class="list">Site goes LIVE!</p>
                <!--end post updates-->
            </div>

            <div id="twitter">
                <img src="img/twitter.png" height="48px" width="140px"><br><br>
                <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/FluffyRabbitzZ" data-widget-id="544642022154723328">Tweets by @FluffyRabbitzZ</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
            </div>



            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy;2014. MCSocial. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS;

```
div#content {
width: 900px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #fff;
height: auto;
border-radius: 2px;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

div#updates {
float: left;
margin-left: 2.6%;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you'll need to clear the `float`. The floated element has been removed from the document flow and no longer pushes other elements down. See this article for various methods: [Clearing Floats](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the `float`.

- Add `overflow` CSS property (for example `:auto`) to the `div#content`.
- A solution for modern browsers :

```
    .div#content:after {
       content:"";
       display:table;
       clear:both;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the floating content:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

before closing yout `div.content`.